# Garbage collection of objects using express

Tags: node.js, express, garbage-collection

I am wondering if I need to remove references to objects that are created in a route in express or that it will be taken care of.

Suppose the following simple situation;

```
class Person
{
    constructor(name, age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    const person = new Person(req.params.name, req.params.age);
    res.send('Persons name is ' + person.name);
})
```

After 100 calls to this route will there be 100 person objects floating around or will this be cleaned up by the Garbage Collection of node?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An object is eligible for garbage collection as long as its reference stops being used.

Since `person` reference isn't passed anywhere, the variable stops to exist at the end of route handler function, the memory it uses will be released on next garbage collection.

If requests are done frequently, it's possible that memory will be occupied with a bunch of `Person` instances until they will be garbage-collected.